# Unable to configure eth1

Tags: network-interface

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit server version in a VM. I am using my own dhcp to configure the IP address. For my machine, I configured adapter 1 as NAT and adapter 2 as Host-only-adapter.

The problem is that my `/etc/network/interfaces` does not show `eth1`. It's only showing `lo` and `eth0`. How can I configure `eth1` to connect between my machine?

If I add

```
auto eth1
Iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.6
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

manually, it will show an error when doing `ifdown`. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo there, prohibiting the correct use via networking-scripts:

"Iface" must be "iface" ...

Best regards
Gerhard

Comment: Got it..it was just a mistake..i should to ifup first to achieve that..